# How to Align the Origin tracking marker to the World Origin as well as XY axes?

Tags: 3d-view, tracking, origin, movie-clip-editor, marker

I have a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wq_79o5O1M4WKauT9juTVu2SkxnAV6Gj/view?usp=sharing) of my monitor with Blender open and I'm tracking the points in the Blender application running inside the monitor I have recorded. I'm planning to have an object animated inside the video and make it look like it is part of the monitor and then it will pop out of the monitor.

[image]

But for some reason I cannot make the marker I set as origin using the *Set Origin* button to position exactly at the *3D View*'s *World Origin*. Also no matter what marker I select and press *Set X-Axis* or *Set Y-Axis* nothing seems to align to the 3D View's X or Y-Axis. I don't quite understand how these buttons work. What am I doing wrong?

I would like the Marker I marked as origin to align to the 3D View's *World Origin* and the X and Y axes to also align to the 3D View's axes as well to make sure the animation plays exactly on this area I tracked. Why does it not work?

[image]

I have tracked the points using Affine Motion Model to make sure I get the exact perspective. I also believe I have set the proper scale to 3 meters as you can see where I selected 2 markers with a distance of 3 meters.

[image]

It is almost working where I had to manually align it but still not perfect. I just need to figure out how to get it perfectly aligned. Anyone? It looks like a bug. It's impossible to align. I mean I have the tracker selected exactly at the origin in the video tracking and I can see the tracking is clearly in 3D space and you can see in the below gif it's almost aligning so setting Set Origin for that origin tracker should have at least positioned the tracking marker in question on the World Origin. Should I log this as a bug?

[image]

**UPDATE**: I think the problem is that I have to specify the sensor width and the focal length but these values are not directly found on any website [not even the manufacturers website](https://www.oppo.com/en/smartphones/series-reno/reno4-5g/specs/) for the Oppo Reno 4. But I received a message from customer support, but I'm not exactly sure which vales I should use. These are the settings I'm using now:

[image]

[image]

Here's the **First Attempt** [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wq_79o5O1M4WKauT9juTVu2SkxnAV6Gj/view?usp=sharing) used for the Motion Tracking and the blend file:

[image]
*Blender 3.6*

Here's the **Second Attempt** [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XayORAT4JdFjPdgP-PwzTldSeqCxStoq/view?usp=sharing) used for the Motion Tracking and the blend file:

[image]

[image]

In my second attempt I almost got it, it's just the size of the empties corresponding to the markers I can't get them smaller or go down to fit the video footage. Is this tracking impossible? I'm so confused. I have tried this type of tracking several times to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that this type of tracking setup is not possible with only a flat plane of markers. Blender will be confused on where is up and down. The amount of data is insufficient to successfully create an aligned scene. There is some more reading available [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-align-the-origin-tracking-marker-to-the-world-origin-as-well-as-xy-axes/1474760).